# How can I unit 2 rows in a 4-row column and leave the rest as it is?

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns, rows

Here is a table I am working on: http://jsbin.com/tifuhute/50/

I have managed to make one column out of 4 rows where it says "1st".but I am wondering how I could unite 2 rows in the second column (where it says "in stock") and leave row 3 and 4 separated.

Comment: like this http://jsbin.com/tifuhute/53/

Comment: you should set `border-collapse:collapse` to make the border perfect like this http://jsbin.com/tifuhute/54/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into the table property `rowspan` where you can set the number of rows you want a column in the table to take up.

```
<tr>
    <td rowspan="2">1st col</td><td>2nd col</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2nd col</td>
</tr>
```